# Sentential Logic Derivation Equivalence Question

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, symbolic-computation

I am having trouble with the following question:

Construct   a   derivation  to  show    the following   two sentences   are equivalent  in  SD.

1. ~(A≡B)    2. (~A≡B)

I am stuck at trying to introduce the material biconditional in order to find 2, because I have no clue how to derive A from B and vice versa with only sentence 1 as my premise.

Am I looking at this the wrong way? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What is SD ? You can check it with truth-table.

Answer (score 0):

1. $\lnot (A \equiv B) \qquad\qquad$ Premise
2. $\qquad \lnot A \qquad\qquad \quad$ Assumption
3. $\qquad \qquad \lnot B \qquad \quad$ Assumption
4. $\qquad \qquad \qquad A \qquad$ Assumption
5. $\qquad \qquad \qquad \bot \qquad \bot Intro \: 2,4$
6. $\qquad \qquad \qquad B \qquad \bot Elim \: 5$
7. $\qquad \qquad \qquad B \qquad$ Assumption
8. $\qquad \qquad \qquad \bot \qquad \bot Intro \: 3,7$
9. $\qquad \qquad \qquad A \qquad \bot Elim \: 8$
10. $\qquad \qquad A \equiv B \qquad \equiv Intro \: 4-6,7-9$
11. $\qquad \qquad \bot \qquad \qquad \bot Intro \: 1,10$
12. $\qquad \lnot \lnot B \qquad\qquad \quad \lnot Intro \: 3-11$
13. $ \qquad B \qquad \qquad\qquad \lnot Elim \: 12$
14. $ \qquad B \qquad \qquad\qquad $ Assumption
15. $ \qquad \qquad A \qquad \qquad$ Assumption
16. $\qquad \qquad \qquad A \qquad$ Assumption
17. $\qquad \qquad \qquad B \qquad Reit \: 14$
18. $\qquad \qquad \qquad B \qquad$ Assumption
19. $\qquad \qquad \qquad A \qquad Reit \: 15$
20. $\qquad \qquad A \equiv B \qquad \equiv Intro \: 16-17,18-19$
21. $\qquad \qquad \bot \qquad \qquad \bot Intro \: 1,20$
22. $\qquad \lnot A \qquad\qquad \quad \lnot Intro \: 15-21$
23. $\lnot A \equiv B \qquad \qquad\quad\equiv Intro \: 2-13,14-22$